# Autodesk forge viewer 2d sheets

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am working one a small platform using forge viewer, in the Revit model there are 2d sheets? Since I am using the view models extension, I can access specific sheets.

My question is there any way to print the sheet with original size similar to Revit from the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an article that describe how to do that : [Print Sheet from Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/print-sheet-viewer)